# Geth: Checkpoint challenge timed out, dropping

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I get a warning in Geth that I was not able to find any information on:

```
Checkpoint challenge timed out, dropping
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Which version of geth are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In geth's code you'll find the snippet bellow https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/handler.go

```
// Start a timer to disconnect if the peer doesn't reply in time
        p.syncDrop = time.AfterFunc(syncChallengeTimeout, func() {
            p.Log().Warn("Checkpoint challenge timed out, dropping", "addr", p.RemoteAddr(), "type", p.Name())
            pm.removePeer(p.id)
        })
```

The comment explain what the log message means